# c# and SQL server's equivalent to mysql_num_rows in PHP

Tags: c#, php, sql-server

I am trying to find the number of rows selected by a select query in ASP.Net - I am using an SQL server database.
What is the c# equivalent to PHP's mysql_num_rows?

Comment: mysql_num_rows (deprecated, btw) retrieves the number of rows from a result set. This command is only valid for statements like SELECT or SHOW that return an actual result set. The equivalent in C# depends on how you are actually getting the result set. Show your C# buts and we'll know for sure.

Comment: For example "SELECT * FROM books"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## System.Data.SqlClient

[SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.recordsaffected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has the RecordsAffected Property to get that value, except for select statements. Therefore you have to count manually or use a `SELECT COUNT(*)` in your SQL statement.

## EntityFramework

Have a look a [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#queryCount) article.

## LINQ2SQL

`var pupilCOunt = (from p in schoolContext.Pupils select p).Count();`

Comment: How would this be achieved with a select query?

Comment: Waht do you mean by *"this"*? You can use a SqlDataReader like this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9kcbe65k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Is it possible to count a select statement - like "select count(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM books);

Comment: Like this: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books You will find a reference here: http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms175997.aspx

Comment: @user3104316: but that's not what you asked. mysql_num_rows doesn't involve COUNT() via SQL, it gives the number of rows in the result set. And this answer is pretty thorough given you haven't indicated what sort of C# code your using. If you want a separate query for count by itself that the SELECT COUNT(*) aforementioned. mysql_num_rows  would return 1 on that count query btw, since it has 1 row in it.

Comment: @KarlKieninger This answer only covers sql dml operation "select". The mysql_num_rows can be used in insert/update/delete to see number of rows updated. So this is not the correct answer. I don't know why it is even marked as correct.

Comment: @Mukus OP asked specifically about SELECT, "I am trying to find the number of rows selected by a select query."

Answer (score 0):

You can use this statement:

```
Select Count(*) From YourTableName
```

or if you want `Serial No.`, you can use:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012; 
GO
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SalesYTD DESC) AS Row, 
    FirstName, LastName, ROUND(SalesYTD,2,1) AS "Sales YTD" 
FROM Sales.vSalesPerson
WHERE TerritoryName IS NOT NULL AND SalesYTD <> 0;
```

Take a look [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The author is looking for number of rows affected by the query. If you're using ADO.NET, look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

ExecuteNonQuery() will return the number of rows affected. Look for what methods you are interested in.

Basically, if you deleted two rows, that will return an int with value 2. If nothing happened it will return 0.

Comment: "if nothing happened it will return 0" - A select statement will also give you that result.

Comment: @ec8or you can't have a select statement when you are returning rows affected for delete/insert/update statements. Unless you create a stored procedure for it. The author is not only trying to perform "select" query.